# How do you bind the selectionIndexes of an NSArrayController to an NSCollectionView?

Tags: macos, cocoa, interface-builder, nsarraycontroller, nscollectionview

I have a storyboard view controller scene the contains an NSArrayController object and an NSCollectionView. The bindings of the collection view look like this:

[image: collection view bindings]

The bindings of the array controller look like this:

[image: array controller bindings]

This seems like it should be enough but the array controller's selectionIndexes doesn't update when the collection view's does. How do I keep these in sync?

I should say, ticking the top two boxes here:

[image]

means they do stay in sync. However, I have to select both and I'd rather not have 'Avoid Empty Selection' as this means the first item in the collection view is always selected when the app starts.